# How to input command line arguments when using pytest in VS Code

Tags: python, pytest, vscode-debugger, vscode-python

I have setup my pytest testing to use optional command line arguments. I would like to run and debug these tests in VS Code. However, I am unable to get the command line arguments to work with VS Code.

Based on the [VS Code instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests) for debugging Python tests, I added the following configuration to launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
    "type": "debugpy",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "purpose": ["debug-test"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": ["--csvfile='..\\example.csv'","--skip", "1"],
    "justMyCode": false
}
```

This differs from the VS code instruction only in that I have added the `args` to pass in my command line arguments. I have another configuration in launch.json, but its purpose is not `"debug-test"` (and when I add args to it, pytest still does not receive my arguments).

My conftest.py includes the following which works when using pytest outside VS Code:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--csvfile", action="store", default=None)
    parser.addoption("--skip", action="store", default=None)

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def skip(request):
    return request.config.option.skip

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def data(request):
    return pd.read_csv(request.config.option.csvfile)
```

The result is that `request.config.option.skip` and `request.config.option.csvfile` are always None (the default value). When I import `sys` and look at `sys.argv`, it does not include the arguments from `launch.json`.

I am using Python 3.12 and VS Code version 1.87.1.

Comment: do you really need to single-quote your csvfile arg? also, you're missing the part of a [mre] where you actually tell us what behaviour you're actually observing.

Comment: @starball I edited to explain the result. I don't think the format of the csvfile argument is relevant. The issue is that the args are not being received by the code in conftest.

Answer (score 0):

I have an similar example where I set `launch.json` to runs with python, not `debugpy` follow the file content.

```
{
    "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "pytest",
    "args": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/your/test_file.py",
        "--csvfile=../example.csv",
        "--skip=1"
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": false
}
```

Comment: Using `python` results in the message: "This configuration will be deprecated soon. Please replace `python` with `debugpy` to use the new Python Debugger extension." so `debugpy` is replacing `python`.

Comment: Specifying the program this way does not work likely because pytest is being called not my program.

Comment: Hum, I update to use module atribute than